# Insert JSONL with two columns of comma separated fields into separate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database-design, sql-insert

I have json datas in the format as shown below.

**the number of objects under 'images'(VIEWS, ROOMS, etc.) varied for each JSON object. Not all objects have VIEWS...POOL, it may only have ROOMS.

```
    "propertyId":{"ea":"12345678","h":"","vo":""},
    "thumbnail":{"width":1000,"height":500,"link":"xxx.jpg"},
    "hero":{"title":"Featured Image","width":1000,"height":669,"link":"yyy.jpg"},
    "images":{
       "VIEWS":[
        {"title":"View from Property","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"a1.jpg"},
        {"title":"View from Property","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"a2.jpg"}
       ],
        "ROOMS":[
            {"title":"Room","width":1000,"height":669,"link":"b1.jpg"},
            {"title":"Room","width":1000,"height":662,"link":"b2.jpg"}
       ],
        "EXTERIOR":[
            {"title":"Terrace","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"c1.jpg"},
            {"title":"Terrace","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"c2.jpg"}
       ],
        "AMENITIES":[
             {"title":"Property Amenity","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"d1.jpg"}
       ],
        "POOL":[
            {"title":"Outdoor Pool","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"e1"},
            {"title":"Outdoor Pool","width":1000,"height":666,"link":"e2.jpg"}
    ]}
    }
```

I wanted to insert the following data into the table with the following format in mysql 8.0 database.
[image]

JSON -> Table Reference

```
HotelId = propertyId.ea
hero_url = hero.link
hero_title = hero.title
media_title = images.(VIEWS/ROOMS/EXTERIOR/...).title 
media_url = images.(VIEWS/ROOMS/EXTERIOR/...).link
>> ...other object may have different category (VIEWS/ROOMS...)
created_at and updated_at = date
```

After searching through the old topics, I was able to use the select statement below to display the format above. However, I'm confused as to it how works when using `INSERT`.

```
  SELECT t.HotelID, t.hero_url, t.hero_title,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.media_title, ',', n.n), ',', -1) media_title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.images, ',', n.n), ',', -1) images
  FROM hotel_sample.property_photos t CROSS JOIN 
  (
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n 
   ) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.media_title) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.media_title, ',', '')))
 ORDER BY HotelID
```

Would appreciate if anyone could show me how I could insert the above JSON data into the table. (MYSQL 8.0)

```
CREATE TABLE `property_photos` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HotelID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hero_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hero_title` text,
  `category` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_title` text,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: Thanks for point out! I have updated my post.

Comment: Answer added into the crosspost at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291156/insert-jsonl-with-two-columns-of-comma-separated-fields-into-separate-rows-in-my